# Canon imageCLASS: how do I perform a factory reset?

Tags: reset, factory-defaults, multi-function-printer

I'm having trouble with a Canon imageCLASS MF8450c printer/scanner/copier (it fails to save scans to SMB shares). I've eliminated the obvious problems, so now I am just looking to do a factory reset of the device and hope that resolves the issue.

I can't figure out how to do a hard reset, though. The manual and support site are not helpful, and hunting through the menu system is like exploring a labyrinth. Any ideas?

Comment: Since it is a business class Printer, that info will not be in any of the publicly available user manuals, only in the private Service manual.

Comment: And to think I couldn't be more angry about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter 'Menu' and then '#' - this gets you into Service Mode.

you can reset settings individually, but you should know what you are doing....

For example should you need to clear the password, you can do so by cycling to the PASSWORD CLEAR option under 6.CLEAR DATA....

You can only find this out from Canon service by faxing them a copy of your purchase receipt.....!! Canon is crazy for making it so difficult and no doubt have lost mucho dinero from professional IT managers who choose other products in Enterprise settings....

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue with an imageCLASS 5950dw and jumped through their proof of purchase hoops.

To reset (the 5950 anyway), menu - 2 - 8 - menu gets you to the service menu, then do copier - function - clear - all to fully reset the machine.

This also works on the MF8280Cw. GWD

Comment: This works for the 8580 model as well. ...and while I am at it, my deepest sympathy for being stuck with one or more of these.

Comment: it worked for MF4880DW as well

Comment: worked for me on MF4570dn